# How to proxy secure web services (HTTPS SSL/TLS) using Mule's <pattern:web-service-proxy>

Tags: web-services, ssl, https, proxy, mule

We have CXF web services running locally that are accessed across HTTPS TLS/SSL. We'd like to expose these services externally using Mule's <pattern:web-service-proxy>. Our question is, can a <pattern:web-service-proxy> be configured to use HTTPS?

We have successfully proxied these services across HTTP using the <pattern:web-service-proxy>. However, when we change the web-service-proxy's inboundAddress and outboundAddress attributes (below) from HTTP URLS to HTTPS URLs we get an error: "The required object/property "tls-key-store" is null".

This works:

```
<pattern:web-service-proxy name="unsecure_ws_proxy"
    inboundAddress="http://localhost:80/services/service_common_name"
    outboundAddress="http://localhost:8080/app_name/proxied_service_name" 
/>
```

This does not work (produces "The required object/property "tls-key-store" is null "):

```
<pattern:web-service-proxy name="secure_ws_proxy"
    inboundAddress="https://localhost:443/services/service_common_name"
    outboundAddress="https://localhost:8443/app_name/proxied_service_name" 
/>
```

We've defined a <tls:context name="TLS_Context"> and assume that if we can get the <pattern:web-service-proxy> to use it then the proxy should work.

Is this assumption correct, and if so how do we tell the <pattern:web-service-proxy> to use the TLS_Context we've defined?  If we are wrong in our assumption, what is the simplest approach in Mule to define what is essentially a pass-thru proxy to CXF SOAP webservices that use the HTTPS protocol?

EDIT:

We're using Mule v.3.6.0.

And in the interest of completeness, our TLS_Context (which we don't yet know how to associate with the pattern:web-service-proxy, if that's even the answer):

```
<tls:context name="TLS_Context" doc:name="TLS Context">
    <tls:trust-store path="${ssl.truststore.path}" password="${ssl.truststore.password}"/>
    <tls:key-store path="${ssl.keystore.path}" password="${ssl.keystore.password}" keyPassword="${ssl.keystore.password}"/>
</tls:context>
```

ANSWER:

Here's the complete solution, based on David's accepted response. The TLS_Context was not needed.  Thank you David:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule 
    xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" 
    xmlns:script="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:pattern="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/pattern"
    xmlns:https="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core 
       http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
       http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http 
       http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
       http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/pattern 
       http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/pattern/current/mule-pattern.xsd
       http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting 
       http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting/current/mule-scripting.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
       http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https 
       http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https/3.0/mule-https.xsd">

    <https:connector name="httpsConnector">
        <!-- Not currently needed 
        <https:tls-client 
            path="${ssl.client.keystore.path}" 
            storePassword="${ssl.client.keystore.password}"/>     
        -->   
        <https:tls-key-store 
            path="${ssl.server.keystore.path}" 
            keyPassword="${ssl.server.keystore.password}" 
            storePassword="${ssl.server.keystore.password}"/>
        <https:tls-server 
            path="${ssl.server.truststore.path}" 
            storePassword="${ssl.server.truststore.password}"/>
    </https:connector>

    <!-- Pattern-based configuration was introduced in Mule v.3.2 to decrease "the amount of 
        noise in its configuration files". Configuration patterns are, by design, not  as 
        powerful as Mule FLows or Services. They have instead been designed for ease of use. 
        (http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation-3.2/display/32X/Understanding+Configuration+Patterns+Using+Mule) -->

    <!-- MULE PATTERN PROXIES -->
    <!-- HTTP -->
    <pattern:web-service-proxy name="http_ws_proxy"
        inboundAddress="http://localhost:80/services/service_common_name"
        outboundAddress="http://localhost:8080/app_name/proxied_service_name" 
    />
    <!-- HTTPS -->
    <pattern:web-service-proxy name="https_ws_proxy"
        inboundAddress="https://localhost:443/services/service_common_name"
        outboundAddress="https://localhost:8443/app_name/proxied_service_name" 
    />

</mule>
```

Comment: Please show the full configuration of your HTTPS connector. Don't forget to mask your JKS passwords. Also please specify the Mule version you're using.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  We're not using an explicit HTTP connector.  We assume that the Mule web-service-proxy Pattern creates it behind the scenes.  The only entry in our Mule configuration file is what we've posted above. And as mentioned, the "unsecure_ws_proxy" works fine (without an explicit connector).  We've chosen a pattern over a flow for reasons of simplicity.

Comment: Mule creates default connectors when you don't explicitly configure them. For HTTPS, the default connector doesn't have any JKS configuration (obviously) so you have to be explicit and configure it.

Comment: Ah ha!  Thanks!  We'll give it a shot.  I assume the connector MUST be named "httpsConnector" as that's how Mule finds it?

Comment: Nope, it finds it by type. The name can be anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure an HTTPS connector with the relevant JKS configuration.

Example:

```
<https:connector name="httpsConnector">
  <https:tls-key-store path="keystore.jks" keyPassword="<Your Password>"
         storePassword="<Your Password>"/>
</https:connector>
```

Reference: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/HTTPS+Transport+Reference

Comment: Thanks for you thoughts, David.  Two concerns: 1) we're trying to avoid using the deprecated HTTP connector that you reference, and 2) even if we do use it, it's not apparent how we would configure the <pattern:web-service-proxy> to use it.

Comment: 1) Then you can't use the `pattern:web-service-proxy`, you need to use a flow. 2) Nothing to do if there's only one `https:connector` in your config.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when your https connector is pointing to an http url. You can either change server/url in the xml or disable https option in the connector:

[image: disable https option in the connector]